# How to map 3D models (clothes) to kinect joints using C#

Tags: virtual, kinect

We are doing a virtual dressing room project and we could map .png image files on body joints. But we need to map 3D clothes to the body and the final out put should be a person(real person not an avatar) wearing a 3D cloth on a live video out put. But we don't know how to do this. Any help is so much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the avatar examples provided in the Kinect for Windows Toolkit?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but we need the 3D cloth to be mapped on a real person in real time. The out put should be a live camera video stream.

Comment: Just notice that this project is not trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for user3588017, its too lengthy but I'll try to explain how to get your project done. First play with XNA with their basic tutorials if you are totally new to 3D gaming. In my project I only focused on bending hands down. For this in you need to create a 3D model in blender and export it to .xna. I used this link as a start. [the very beginning](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/230540/Animating-single-bones-in-a-Blender-3D-model-with#SkinningSampleProject132)  Actually this is the most hardest part after this you know how to animate your model using maths. Then you need to map kinect data as (x,y,z) to the parts of your model.
Ex:- map the model rotation to kinect's model rotation. For this I used simple calculations like measuring the depth of the shoulders and calculating the rotated angle and applied it to my cloth model.